# How to import url in css file from environment variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I have index.css file in React app and I am importing an external css file as below.

`@import url('https://externalurldev01.blob.core.windows.net/XXX/index.css');`

And this url will differ for different env.

```
Dev : @import url('https://externalurldev01.blob.core.windows.net/XXX/index.css');
QA : @import url('https://externalurltest01.blob.core.windows.net/XXX/index.css');
PROD : @import url('https://externalurlprod01.blob.core.windows.net/XXX/index.css');
```

How can I dynamically do the import based on env.

For now I have a workaround of creating three index.css as index-dev.css,index-qa.css,index-prod.css file and import it conditionally from the js file.

But I am looking for some solution so that I need not create three files. Rather get the env from environment variable. Something like below

`@import url('https://externalurl"+process.env.REACT_APP_ENV+"01.blob.core.windows.net/XXX/index.css');`

But the concatenation is not working.

Answer (score 1):

`process.env` is only available on the backend so you can not use it in css or js in browser. The way I usually do this is to populate the value on `data-*` attribute in html and then extract this attribute value in css using the `attr()` function or `dataset` property in js.

Comment: Thank you!! Can you please give a reference - so that I can check the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the problem.

I am dynamically importing the css file as below.

```
    useEffect(() => {
      var head = document.head;
      var link = document.createElement("link");
  
      link.type = "text/css";
      link.rel = "stylesheet";
      link.href = window.REACT_APP_THEME;
  
      head.appendChild(link);
  
      return () => { head.removeChild(link); }
  
    }, []);
```

Since the app is deployed in Kubernetes cluster, so getting setting the window variable from the configmap.